# OpenLayers lineString redraw after point movement

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have been looking at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/am15oq1r/

I have tried to modify it, in order that I may pass any number of points into it (rather then the 3 that it uses as an example).

My issue is that the lineString joining the points, simply disappears when I move the point.

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can point (no pun intended!) out to me where I have gone wrong.

I have basically created an array containing the points and then loop through the array to apply any operations which they require.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ol/ol3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #map {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0em;
    bottom: 0em;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
}
</style>

<title></title>



</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() });

var aa = new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point([000000, 000000]), draggable: true});
var bb = new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point([000000, 100000]), draggable: true});
var cc = new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point([100000, 000000]), draggable: true});

var pointsArray = [aa, bb, cc];

var line = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.LineString([]));
var defaultRoute = new ol.style.Style({
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
     color: '#008800',
     width: 4
   }),
   fill: new ol.style.Fill({
     color: 'rgba(255, 55, 55, 1)'
   }),
   image: new ol.style.Circle({
     radius: 7,
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: '#ff5555'
     }),
     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
       color: '#000000',
       width: 1
     }),
   })
});

line.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 2}),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'red'})
}));

var vectorFeatures = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++) {
    pointsArray[i].setStyle(defaultRoute);
    vectorFeatures.push(pointsArray[i]);
}


function updateRoute (event) {
  var lsArray = [];
  var lsCoords;
      for (var i = 0; i < vectorFeatures.length; i++) {
        lsCoords = vectorFeatures[i].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        lsArray.push(lsCoords);
      }
    var ls = new ol.geom.LineString(lsArray);
    line.setGeometry(ls);
    vectorFeatures.push(line);
}

updateRoute();

for (var i = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++) {
    pointsArray[i].on('change', updateRoute); //line disappears
    //pointsArray[i].on('mousemove', updateRoute); //line does not move
}

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({ features: vectorFeatures }),
    style: defaultRoute
});
    console.info(layer);

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    layers: [baseLayer, layer],
    view: new ol.View({center: [0, 0], zoom: 7})
});

var movingFeature = null;

map.on('pointerdown', function (event) {
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(event.originalEvent);
    movingFeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
//        console.info(feature);
        return feature.get('draggable') ? feature : undefined;
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

map.on('pointerup', function (event) {
    movingFeature = null;
});

map.getTarget().addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (movingFeature) {
        var coordinates = map.getEventCoordinate(event);
        movingFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(coordinates);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Neil.

Comment: One thing: `var line = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.LineString([]));` should be `var line = new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([]) });`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would try updating the layer `source` rather than it's underlying array (`vectorFeatures`).  You should be able to get a collection of features that will have events registered to make sure the line gets re-rendered when you update it in updateRoute().

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Timh.
I have amended my live var.  Still no joy.
What is confusing me, is that the JSFiddle works, and all I have done is replace the separate aa, bb, cc objects with an array of them, then looped through the array where the JSFiddle was simply using the hardwired geometries.
Can you clarify what you mean by updating the layer source, rather than vectorLayers please?
Thanks again.

Comment: Ok.
Thanks to the hints by @Timh, I have solved it.
The `line` var needed changing (as Tim pointed out) and also the `updateRoute` function needed to work with the `pointsArray` values and not the `vectorFeatures` values